# Why am I getting segmentation fault errors in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-1.9.3

While running RSpec, ***sometimes*** I am getting the following error. Simply saving the file runs RSpec and sometimes it disappears.

```
[BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p374 (2013-01-15 revision 38858) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:000f38 d:000f38 TOP   

* Loaded features:

0 enumerator.so
1 /Users/george/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.2/enc/encdb.bundle
2 /Users/george/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.2/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
3 /Users/george/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults.rb
4 /Users/george/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.2/rbconfig.rb
5 /Users/george/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/deprecate.rb
6 /Users/george/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/exceptions.rb
```

The error in my code is `NoMethodError:       undefined method`.

Why is this creating a seg fault error? How do I turn off the verbose 473 line output?

Comment: Can you show your code and tests?
And please improve your question including repro steps.

Answer (score -1):

It can be a hardware problem this time. No, really. I had a similar issue and when I changed computer the problem went away.

Comment: I seriously doubt that actual hardware is the problem. There's too many layers between hardware and Ruby for it to be the culprit.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm on my case I'm 100% it was. I changed the memories and never had this error again. Funny world when the problem is really the hardware - you never beat.